# Trying to experiment shared preferences for the first time

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        SharedPreferences sp = this.getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomNum = rand.nextInt( 1000 );

        editor.putString("EQUATION_KEY_" + String.valueOf(randomNum), "");
        editor.commit();

        String str = sp.getString(String.valueOf(randomNum), "");

        textView.setText(str);
    }
}
```

I don't know why this isn't working just to display the saved text to the screen. This is what the logcat says:

```
02-18 10:11:24.988 3196-3196/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-18 10:11:25.169 3196-3196/com.example.luke.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.luke.myapplication-2/lib/x86
02-18 10:11:25.252 3196-3217/com.example.luke.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-18 10:11:25.430 3196-3217/com.example.luke.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-18 10:11:25.749 3196-3217/com.example.luke.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-18 10:11:25.750 3196-3217/com.example.luke.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab78ee40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-18 10:11:38.677 3196-3202/com.example.luke.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.161ms
```

Please help me, I am a noob, but want to learn.

Comment: That logcat has no errors in it. W = Warn, D = Debug, I = Info. Notice there no `E/` for Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create common class for your Application Follow bellow Steps :

**Step 1:**
Create Application level Class

```
public class AppConfig extends Application {

private static AppConfig appInstance;
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor;
private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    appInstance = this;
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    setContext(getApplicationContext());

}

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public static void setContext(Context mctx) {
    mContext = mctx;
}


public static AppConfig getAppInstance() {
    if (appInstance == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("The application is not created yet!");
    return appInstance;
}

/**
 * Application level preference work.
 */
public static void preferencePutInteger(String key, int value) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putInt(key, value);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static int preferenceGetInteger(String key, int defaultValue) {
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void preferencePutBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putBoolean(key, value);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static boolean preferenceGetBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void preferencePutString(String key, String value) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(key, value);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static String preferenceGetString(String key, String defaultValue) {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void preferencePutLong(String key, long value) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putLong(key, value);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static long preferenceGetLong(String key, long defaultValue) {
    return sharedPreferences.getLong(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void preferenceRemoveKey(String key) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.remove(key);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static void clearPreference() {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.clear();
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

}
```

**Step 2:** Define this class into Manifest.xml in Application tag like this

```
<application
    android:name=".AppConfig">
 </application>
```

**Step 3:**
You can use below code into your activity

```
AppConfig.preferencePutInteger("Key",Value);
AppConfig.preferenceGetInteger("Key", 0)
```

Done Happy coding.... :) I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

In this line of code, instead of using your randomNum as store value, you append it to your storage key.

```
 editor.putString("EQUATION_KEY_" + String.valueOf(randomNum), "");
```

It should be

```
 editor.putString("EQUATION_KEY_",  String.valueOf(randomNum));
```

Comment: OP would like to know "why this isn't working just to display the saved text to the screen". I think you're not wrong, but you're only halfway there.